# Ask The Way To London

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, reported-speech

Could this sentence:

> He ***asked the way to*** the London.

be wrong?  Because according to this [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ask_1), "ask" means to tell somebody to give you something.  Using this definition would suggest that my original sentence would translate as:

> He told somebody to give him ***the way to*** the London.

which seems to be missing something.  Would this modified original sentence be better?

> He asked ***the information about the way to*** the London.

because it would translate to:

> He told somebody to ***give him the information about the way to*** the London.

Answer (score 1):

No. In this case, you are asking somebody to give you something; the something is directions to London.

In many cases, this usage of "ask" is followed by a clause beginning with "for":

> He asked her for a pen made of a partridge feather.

In the case of certain things being asked for, including directions, the "for" may be omitted. Both:

> He stopped to ask for directions to the Chuckle Hut.

and

> He stopped to ask directions to the Chuckle Hut.

are correct; the first is more formal but the second is still understandable.

When using the expression "the way" to mean "directions," the "for" is always omitted,

> He stopped to ask the way to the Chuckle Hut.

This is more common in British English but is understandable to American speakers as well.

Comment: Is it okay to write: "he ***asked*** a pen made of a partridge feather"?

Comment: no - it would be 'he asked _for_ a pen' made of a partridge feather. 'Asked a pen' makes it sound like he is talking to a pen, like 'He asked a police officer...'

Answer (score 0):

No, 'he asked the way to London' is perfectly acceptable. Your dictionary also defines ask as:

> to say or write something in the form of a question, in order to get information

There's nothing grammatically wrong with 'He asked about the way to London', but the common phrase is 'He asked the way'. It's just evolved like that, I guess.

Comment: So, I could write "he ***asked*** the weather" to mean "he ***asked about*** the weather"?

Comment: Nope. I've no idea why (someone more learned in the technicalities is required), but you would say 'asked about the weather'. There's nothing grammatically _wrong_ with 'asked about the way to London', but the common phrase is simply 'ask the way'. It's just evolved that way I suppose.

Comment: So, "*ask the way* to some place" is technical jargon?

Comment: Not technical jargon, just a kind of universal colloquialism.

Comment: @meatie, you can ask someone their age, and you can ask them the time. I think the reason you can't "ask someone the weather" is because weather is a multidimensional thing. There is temperature, wind speed, humidity, etc. Weather changes depending on place and time, and so on. What exactly would you be asking about?

Comment: @Dangph So, both "to ***ask for*** the way to London" and "to ***ask*** the way to London" are standard English.  But for the pair "to ***ask for*** more time to work on a project" and "to ***ask*** more time to work on a project", the latter is not acceptable?

Comment: @meatie correct - the latter is not acceptable